# Объект класса в redux toolkit

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit

Если я в состояние redux-toolkit сохраню класс и изменю переменную класса через метод, то эти изменения будут обновлены в redux store автоматически, или нет?

То есть допустим у меня есть слайс. `const initialState:IGraphic[]=[new ClassGraphic(0,0,0,0,0,0,[],[]), new ClassGraphic(0,0,0,0,0,0,[],[])] //далее пойдут возможные экшены`

И есть сам класс графика.

```
export class ClassGraphic{
    maxPrice:number;
    minPrice:number;
    yDown:number;
    startCandle:number;
    candleWidth:number;
    candleSpacing:number;
    drawingElements:ClassDrawingElements | null;
    xLeft:number;
    data:string[][];
    allData:string[][];
    mainCanvas:ClassMainCanvas | null;
    dateCanvas:ClassDateCanvas | null;
    priceCanvas:ClassPriceCanvas | null;
    constructor(
        maxPrice:number,
        minPrice:number,
        startCandle:number,
        candleWidth:number,
        candleSpacing:number,
        xLeft:number,
        data:string[][],
        allData:string[][],
        ){
        this.maxPrice=maxPrice
        this.minPrice=minPrice
        this.startCandle=startCandle
        this.candleWidth=candleWidth
        this.candleSpacing=candleSpacing
        this.xLeft=xLeft
        this.yDown=0
        this.data=data
        this.allData=allData
        this.mainCanvas=null
        this.dateCanvas=null
        this.priceCanvas=null
        this.drawingElements=null
    }
    public setDrawingClass (drawingElements:ClassDrawingElements){
        this.drawingElements=drawingElements
    }
    public DrawGraphic(
        xLeft:number,
        yDown:number,
        dopHeight:number,
        maxPrice:number,
        minPrice:number,
        startCandle:number,
        candleWidth:number,
        candleSpacing:number,
        data:string[][],
        allData:string[][],
        distance:string,
        isPressed:boolean,
        pressedElement:IFlag,
    ){
        this.maxPrice=maxPrice
        this.minPrice=minPrice
        this.startCandle=startCandle
        this.candleWidth=candleWidth
        this.candleSpacing=candleSpacing
        this.xLeft=xLeft
        this.data=data
        this.allData=allData
        this.yDown=yDown
        this.mainCanvas?.DrawCanvas(dopHeight)
        this.dateCanvas?.DrawCanvas(distance,isPressed,pressedElement)
        this.priceCanvas?.DrawCanvas(pressedElement)
    }
    DrawElements(graphic:IGraphic, x:number, y:number,copyY:number,pressedElement:IFlag,ifHoverFlag:IFlag,isPressed:boolean){
        DrawAllElements(graphic,this,this.startCandle,x,y,pressedElement,isPressed,undefined,ifHoverFlag,copyY)
    }
}
```

И если я возьму в каком-то компоненте использую метод DrawGraphic(). То получу ли я обновленный класс с помощью useAppSelector `const graphics=useAppSelector(state=>state.graphics) // и в graphics будут обовленыые, свежие классы`?

Comment: Покажите кодом, что именно вы делаете. В теории, если вы передаете ссылку на объект, и его меняете, то он изменится(и событие изменения данных не произойдет

Comment: кода самого нет, я только проектирую, суть в том, что обновляется ли класс в стейте redux-toolkit, если я взаимодействую не напрямую с слайсом, а через методы класса?

Comment: С уверенность на 90% - если положить вредакс объект, вытащить его в компоненте и обновить(без диспатча в редакс), то объект изменится везде и события изменения не будет. Класс, тот же объект

Comment: Спасибо, если что отпишу!